# Boundaries of a triple integral

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus

I want a general method for finding the boundaries of a triple integral.

And I have a integral of a function over a region given by the condition $$\sqrt x+\sqrt y +\sqrt z \le 1.$$
what are the boundaries of integration?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't imagine there is one fool-proof method that will always work. My recommendation is to look for constraints on your variables and to try to visualize or graph the volume you are integrating over.

Looking at your specific problem you can quickly establish bounds: $x\geq0$, $y\geq0$ and $z\geq0$. Additionally none of the variables can be greater than 1. Next consider the curved surface, in this case the equation: $$\sqrt{x}+\sqrt{y}+\sqrt{z}=1$$
From this we can see that $z$ can go from $0$ to $(1-\sqrt{x}-\sqrt{y})^2$. Additionally if we look at $z=0$ we see that $y$ can go from $0$ to $(1-\sqrt{x})$.
So your integral becomes:

$$\int_0^1\int_0^{\left(1-\sqrt{x}\right)^2}\int_0^{\left(1-\sqrt{x}-\sqrt{y}\right)^2}f(x,y,z)\,dz\,dy\,dx$$

Edit: The following is the surface defined by your inequality. It may help you with your visualization.
[image]

Comment: Wrong: what happens when $\sqrt{x} + \sqrt{y} > 1$?

Answer (score 0):

Let's say we want the $x$ integral on the outside and the $z$ integral on the inside.

Given $x$ and $y$ with $x \ge 0$ and $y \ge 0$, we need $z \ge 0$ and $\sqrt{z} = 1 - \sqrt{x} - \sqrt{y}$.  So the inner integral can have 
$z$ going from $0$ to $(1 - \sqrt{x} - \sqrt{y})^2$, but we need
$\sqrt{x} + \sqrt{y} \le 1$.  Thus $y$ should go from $0$ to $(1-\sqrt{x})^2$ (which will always be $\ge 0$ and $\le 1$ if $0 \le x \le 1$).  The result is

$$ \int_0^1 \int_0^{(1-\sqrt{x})^2} \int_0^{1-\sqrt{x}-\sqrt{y})^2} f(x,y,z)\; dz\; dy\; dx $$